# JavaFX , tableView missing data in one column

Tags: java, javafx

Only one column in the table view in name "col_rib" did not show data

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> col_rib; 

col_rib.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String> ("rib"));
```

here is the code of the controller:

```
 @FXML
private TableView<User> tableUser;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, Integer> col_id;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> col_nom;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> col_prenom;


@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> col_date;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, Integer> col_cin;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, Integer> col_tel;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> col_adresse;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> col_rib;


//    ObservableList<User> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<User> oblist ;



@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Integer>("id"));
    col_nom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String> ("nom"));
    col_prenom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String> ("prenom"));
    col_rib.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String> ("rib"));
    col_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String> ("DateNaissance"));
    col_cin.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Integer>("cin"));
    col_tel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Integer>("telephone"));
    col_adresse.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String> ("adresse"));




    Admin_service as = new Admin_service() ;
    oblist = as.getAll();
    tableUser.setItems(oblist);
```

others columns than "col_rib" work perfectly

any Help plz !

Comment: what does the getter for rib look like?

Comment: thnx u very much ! it works perfectly when i add the getter !

Comment: welcome. if you want it to be editable you need a property accessor instead ;)

Comment: grateful ! thank you again  !  :D ;)

Comment: Interesting question ... and welcome to upvote rights ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you must to add the getter of "col_rib" attribute !
thank u KAI for your comment !